# Getting 404 error for CSS and JS files in ExpressJS application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to the client side programming, building a nodeJS express sample application, but getting 404 error for loading script and CSS.

Please find the below wolder structure:
[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFh2c.jpg)

HTML page is as below:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Favorite Book</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/main.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/libs/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/libs/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/libs/js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../public/libs/js/script.js"></script>
```

Script error getting from browser is below:

GET http://localhost:3000/public/libs/js/script.js

Answer (score 3):

you should set static path in app.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

then defind source without public path like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" type="text/css"/>
```